# fill the Null place in Spotfire

Tags: null, spotfire

I am using Spotfire, and have a small question to process the data table, the original table is like this :

[image]

I want to fill the number for Null places, the final output could be like this :

[image]

or, the result can be like this as well :

[image]
Thanks for your help!

---

solution from @scsimon
 thanks for ur solution, but there is an error for it , when the time is same, then the status is wrong :(

[image]

Comment: There must be more columns available that makes you think this is an error... if there are no other columns, then the order or row that the number 2 is on doesn't matter. If there are more columns then you haven't given us what we need and you need to be more careful in your wording.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i thought i have figured out out the problem. the logic of the error is, some timestampts would be same even though their corresponding status is different. I just added a new RowID column(which just present the number of the row), in this way, it can avoid the problem of the duplicate value in  timestamp column i mentioned, then use this RowID column to replace the timestamp column. but still, thanks a lot for your idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to replace the value in a current column, not create a new one, you want to do this with a transformation.

On the tool bar click:

`Insert > Transformations > Calculate and Replace Column (Add) >`

A window will pop up. In the `Expression` portion enter `ValueForMax([Timestamp],[Status]) OVER (AllPrevious([Timestamp]))`

Click Ok. Click Ok. Your column will now show `0` where there were `NULL`

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, but it is not replace the null value, but depends on its previous value, pls refer to the graph :)

Comment: actually, some Null would be replaced by 2 or 3 as well

Comment: @ZAWD then you have to determine the rule for if it's replaced with a 2 or a 3... what chooses that?

Comment: it depends on its latest status, see the first row, the status is 0, then the other rows below the first row will be 0  until the status is 2 or others.

Comment: Then use IF([Status] IS NULL, Previous([Status]), [Status])

Comment: But i think the Previous function must be coupled with Over.

Comment: I tried ur code, but it says that couldnt find the Previous function

Comment: but i have not idea what should i put before the over function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122911/discussion-between-scsimon-and-zawd).